# Using mpi.h,how to send more than 4 integers per processor, using mpi.h's MPI_Altoallv?

Tags: c, mpi

Using mpi.h in C, with 4 processors, each processor has allocated a buffer (integer) of 8 elements, and another array (p) of 6 elements.
I initialize each p array of each processor in a way that it contains an increasing sequence of numbers (processor 0 has 0,1,2,3,4,5 ; processor 2 has 6,7,etc...).
Now I want to use MPI_Alltoallv to send each piece of the matrix in an unique array (buffer), but since the matric is 4x6, I want to send 8 elements to processor 0, 8 elements to processor 1, 4 elements to processor 2 and 4 elements to processor 3.
So i tried to do that in my code, which I link:

http://pastebin.com/EgGt6Asz

But it fails to achieve what I want to do: it just receive in buffer a 4x4 matrix, ignoring elements of index bigger than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [specification](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node75.html) of alltoallv:
`sendcounts` integer array equal to the group size specifying the number of elements to send to each processor

so you should set send buffer different for each processor
say

```
if (myid==0)
send[]=[6,0,0,0]
if(myid==1)
send[]=[2,4,0,0]
if(myid==2)
send[]=[0,4,2,0]
if(myid==1)
send[]=[0,0,2,4]
```

and displacement array accordingly.

```
if (myid==0)
disp[]=[0,0,0,0]
if(myid==1)
disp[]=[0,2,0,0]
if(myid==2)
disp[]=[0,0,4,0]
if(myid==1)
disp[]=[0,0,0,2]
```

Currently you have setted each value as 1, so all processors are getting 1 value from each processor. Thus 4 values in all.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was trying to do (I wanted p0 to send 2 elements to p0, 2 to p1, 1 to p2 and 1 to p3, in a way to obtain a transponed matrix in buffer), but this made me understand how to do it, and I rewritten the code this way: http://pastebin.com/0QBjA8uk